# Creating a constraint on multiple columns based upon the value of another column

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a check on a few columns in my database that forces them to be null unless the value of another column is yes. I've tried something like

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE1
ALTER Column1
CHECK (Column2 = 'y')
```

But that doesn't seem to be working. Is there a way to do it like this, or is there a better way around this problem? Any help in the right direction would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to require that `col1` is null unless `col2` is 'y', you can write your CHECK constraint as:

```
col2 = 'y' OR col1 IS NULL
```

If you additionally want to require that `col1` must have a value when `col2` is 'y', you can write the constraint as:

```
(col2 = 'y' AND col1 IS NOT NULL) OR (col2 != 'y' AND col1 IS NULL)
```

You should write this as a table constraint, btw.  I don't think a column constraint is allowed to refer to other columns.  (But a column constraint is just another way of writing a table constraint anyway, so you don't lose anything by writing table constraints instead.)

Answer (score 0):

so many option is there ...

but check usually used to check the row.. and if condition doesn't satisfying then this row will ignore by database...

you can try trigger ...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_table1_col2
   before INSERT ON table1
   DECLARE
     duplicate_info EXCEPTION;
   BEGIN
     if :new.coloumn2 <>'y'
then :new.column1 := null;
end if;     
   END trg_table1_col2;
```

it may be having some syntax error .. please check and correct it .. 
I don't have database in my machine as of now ..

Comment: That trigger is risky, because it'll silently ignore the `column1` value in the INSERT statement, instead of reporting an error that the row is unacceptable.  That can lead to loss of data.

Comment: If your column2 is not 'y' then you want to same null as column1 isn't it?

if so then trigger option is not risky as what you have commented ..

Comment: you can show exception also if you want to give user attention on hs fault about this scenario... but see as you have asked ** check on a few columns in my database that forces them to be null unless the value of another column is yes** then database (trigger will do ) will force to to store null in this column ..

Comment: If you throw an error, the application knows its data wasn't inserted.  If you force the value to null, the application thinks its data *was* inserted — since the INSERT statement succeeded — but it actually wasn't.  That can be important.  Imagine that the value in `column1` is an important document written by a user, and when the application does the INSERT without getting an error, it tells the user "your file was saved successfully."  But the file was actually ignored and replaced with a null.